# How can I get the micophone volume in JS for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, audio

I'm using this code - it works in Win chrome however not in android.
How should I change it for android browsers?

```
 const volumeMeterEl = document.getElementById('volumeMeter');
const startButtonEl = document.getElementById('startButton');
startButtonEl.onclick = async () => {
    startButtonEl.disabled = true;
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false });
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const mediaStreamAudioSourceNode = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    const analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    mediaStreamAudioSourceNode.connect(analyserNode);

    const pcmData = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);
    const onFrame = () => {
        analyserNode.getFloatTimeDomainData(pcmData);
        let sumSquares = 0.0;
        for (const amplitude of pcmData) { sumSquares += amplitude*amplitude; }
    volume=Math.sqrt(sumSquares / pcmData.length);
        volumeMeterEl.value = volume;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame(onFrame);
};`
```